# PostgreSQL interesting issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 5 relations:

```
Event (etype, description)                      primary key - etype

City (cname, country, population)               primary key - cname

Disaster (cname, dyear, etype, casualties)      primary keys - cname, dyear

Prediction (cname, etype, casualties)           primary keys - cname, etype

Measures (etype, provider, mcost, percent)      primary keys - etype, provider
```

etype - type of disaster.

provider - police, fire department...

mcost - cost of those providers.

percent - the percent of the providers to avoid casualties.

I need to write a query which finds out 2 successful providers for predicted disasters in a city. The cost for both must not be higher than 1,000,000.

2 Successful providers defined as the max percent possible summed.

I have this so far:

```
select
from prediction, measures as m1, measures as m2
where m1.provider < m2.provider AND (m1.mcost + m2.mcost <= 1000000) 
AND m1.percent + m2.percent >= all (select
```

I don't know if this partial query right and what to do next.

Comment: "I don't know if this partial query right" --- so run it and see?

Comment: Run partial query? why?

Comment: please learn to use explicit ANSI standard join syntax e.g. "inner join" "left outer join". Deny yourself the option of placing commas between table names in the from clause.

Comment: Why would anyone run a partial query? **To see if that bit works.** If no, fix it. If yes, go on to the next bit.

Comment: No **** thrown by me. You asked why someone would run a partial query. If you are unwilling to accept advice, fine, but there is no need to toss insults around. Running partial code is a valid approach to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calculating two CTEs: all distinct provider pairs and the max percent of each pair. Then join the two CTEs in main query:

```
WITH provider_pairs AS (
       SELECT m1.provider AS provider1, m2.provider AS provider2, 
              m1.percent + m2.percent AS sum_percent
       FROM measures m1
       INNER JOIN  measures m2 ON m1.provider < m2.provider
       INNER JOIN prediction p ON p.etype = m1.etype AND p.etype = m2.etype
       WHERE (m1.mcost + m2.mcost <= 1000000) 
  ),
   max_pct AS (
       SELECT MAX(sum_percent) AS max_percent
       FROM provider_pairs p
  )

SELECT p.provider1, p.provider2
FROM provider_pairs p
INNER JOIN max_pct m ON p.sum_percent = m.max_percent
```

Comment: The part of max_pct... (rows 9-11) is connected to the WITH clause?

Comment: And also i can't understand how it'll choose the pair with the max percent

Comment: [`WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) defines the CTEs which can be one or comma separated list of more than one. The last `SELECT` statement's `JOIN` clause chooses the pair with max percent (which can be more than one pair due to ties) as it joins both CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

If i got the question correct, you are looking for all pairs of providers from measures table whose combined mcost is less than 100000 and whose combined percentage is the maximum

See if the following helps
One way of doing this would be as follows

1. Cartesian product the tables and filter out the self join condition
2. Sum up the percentage column and sum up the mcost colum
3. Filter out summed_up mcost to be <100000
4. order by summed_up percentage desc and get the first value.

I created a test case as follows

```
create table measures(provider varchar(50),mcost int, percent int);

insert into measures values('Police',30000,80);
insert into measures values('Fire Department',50000,40);
insert into measures values('Military',40000,50);
insert into measures values('Medical',45000,70);

select * from (
         select row_number() over(order by x.max_percent desc) as rnk
               ,x.*
           from (
         select a.provider
                ,b.provider
                ,greatest(a.provider,b.provider) as combo_pair
                ,a.percent+b.percent as summed_percent
                ,a.mcost+b.mcost as summed_mcost
                ,max(a.percent+b.percent) over(partition by greatest(a.provider,b.provider)) as max_percent
           from measures a
           join measures b
             on 1=1
         where a.provider <> b.provider    
           and a.mcost+b.mcost <100000 /*Check for the combined cost to be <100000*/
         )x
         where x.max_percent=x.summed_percent
)y
where y.rnk=1
```

**Updated DEMO**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=7db3297721500ee926c590207a1e57e7

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am not allowed to use neither order by nor limit here :)